# enforcing serialization in rapid successive calls to `setState`

Tags: reactjs

This is a SSCCE. We have a simple counter, a button to increment it once, and a button to increment it three times in a row:

[image]

The below naive implementation doesn't work due to the asynchronous nature of `setState`:

```
const App = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function() {
    return {counter: 0};
}
, incCounter() {
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1});
}
, incCounterInBurst() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        this.incCounter();

}
, render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{this.state.counter}</div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.incCounter}>
                    inc
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.incCounterInBurst}>
                    inc X 3
                </button>                
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
});
export default App;
```

Specifically, if you click the `inc X 3` button using the above implementation, it will implement the counter only by 1.

I have found two methods to make this work:

## method 1

Pass a `(prevState, props)=>newState` function in `setState` as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate). The only thing that needs to change is the `incCounter` method:

```
, incCounter() {
    this.setState((prevState, _)=>{return {counter: prevState.counter+1}});
}
```

## method 2

I discovered another method that forces serialization (for lack of a better word) of the `setState` calls after the current stack clears. This method leaves the `incCounter` method exactly as it initially was in the naive implementation and changes the `incCounterInBurst` method instead:

```
const TimerMixin = require('react-timer-mixin'); 
const App = React.createClass({
    mixins: [TimerMixin],
    ...    
    , incCounter() { // same as in the initial, erroenous implementation
        this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1});
    }
    , incCounterInBurst() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            this.setTimeout( ()=>{this.incCounter();}, 0);
    }
    ...
}
```

I haven't seen `method 2` mentioned anywhere but do you think it offers any advantages over `method 1` or is there some other more performant / idiomatic way to handle this? The constraint is that we obviously need the `incCounterInBurst` method to leverage the existing `incCounter` method, not simply change the state itself.

Comment: First method is better. Its simple and works. Mixins are discouraged.